# Laptop display connection

Tags: display, connection, connectors

Is there any way how to connect Dell Latirude D630 display B141PW03 V.0 to RPi?

I have working digitizer, working notebook which is useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I made an tutorial about this ;)
Hopefully it works for you, if you have any questions let me know!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKqygvB7Hds

Comment: Thanks, but I need just connect that display somehow directly to RPi, uaing HDMI/AV/onboard display connextor. Its just for console output and playing video in loop. I dont want to use that laptop. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood :)

Comment: Its ok. Googling for hours its totaly useless. Maybe I should ask some chinese sellers on ebay for something. It seems that connectors on that display are made just only for Dell Latitude D6x0 series...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SOXMDb4cjI
This is what you are looking for I guess :)

Comment: Yea, exactly. I found it like 15 mins before you posted it. Make it as answer, I will set it as right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since both HDMI ports in both the Pi and in your lap top are output ports, you can't connect Pi directly to your lap top.

For the first time setup, try using the HDMI port in your TV screen. After that try googling `How to connect to Raspberry Pi remotely`.

You will be using some apps like `PuTTY` with `Real VNC` or `Xming` as an alternative of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

you need LVDS controller boards for exact model of your Laptop Screen incase of yours [you can buy from here](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/lcd-controller-board-hdmi)  so after having the board you need to have some case for sitting you can use acrylic glass wood or plastic!

**Make Sure you have the correct LVDS driver**

**Hint: You can Buy the VGA version of LVDS and converting it in to HDMI using Cheap converter or buy the HDMI version Driver!**